# file line count in ksh unix

Tags: unix, ksh

I am trying to get line count from a file like below in a ksh script. But it returns nothing :

```
filerecordcount= $((`wc -l <../data/act.dat`))
```

I also tried these :

```
    filerecordcount= `wc -l <../data/act.dat`

    filerecordcount= $(wc -l <../data/act.dat)
```

When i print the variable its not printing the value in the variable.

```
print "Record Count in .dat file : $filerecordcount." 1>&2;
```

But when i try the same from command prompt it returns the count

```
wc -l<../data/act.dat
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to give the space after the = in assigning part. Use the below one. It will work fine. But don't forget to print the variable filerecordcount.

UPDATE:

filerecordcount=$((`wc -l <../data/act.dat`))

Comment: now the error i get is  -    wc -l <../data/act.dat: bad number

Comment: perfect !. got it. one space spoiled my day :(

Answer (score 2):

Simplify simplify.  Your backquotes are doing the command expansion, and their output is being processed by `$((...))` as an arithmetic expression. It's a little redundant.

```
filerecordcount=$(wc -l < ../data/act.dat)
```

No space after the `=`, and just one level of command expansion.

Alternately you can use process substitution:

```
read filerecordcount < <(wc -l < ../data/act.dat)
```

Or you could even do this without a subshell, using a loop:

```
filerecordcount=0
while read junk; do ((filerecordcount++)); done < ../data/act.dat
```